# Why are my appliances failing and the breaker tripping?

Tags: electrical

10 yr old washer would not come on so it wash replaced with a working 4yr old one. I did 3 loads of laundry not on same day then tonight it would not come on. The breaker was off. I flipped it on and washer got wispy smoke from the back near the top. Outlet started to hiss. Unplugged it and the freezer which are plugged to same outlet. When I turned the breaker back on the freezer does not hiss in either outlet but the washer does. Only 2 things that have ever been plugged into it and only things on that breaker. I wonder if the fist dryer was broken after all but that's not the question. Can it be the outlet?

Comment: I would call a reputable service company to trouble shoot the problem. It sounds as if there is a problem with the washer

Comment: Sounds like the outlet was overloaded, or a loose connection , the arcing could have damaged the control circuits in the washer. First plug the freezer into another outlet with an extension cord to prevent loosing the frozen food. Next with that breaker turned off pull the outlet and look for burned wires and or insulation, I find many times that a 15 amp breaker used with back stabs to be the problem if this is a 15 amp circuit it was probably over loaded when the washer and fridge compressor were trying to start at the same time , current code requires a 20 amp laundry circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with NEC Article 220.52 (B). which requires a separate laundry circuit for the  washer only. So you will need to find a second circuit for the freezer. Next you purchased a used washer and we have no idea what type condition it is in and it has no warranty (see comments above). Now that you have probably overloaded the circuit with a bad washer, you have picked up "Hissing" in the receptacle. This means you have probably caused some damage to the receptacle or its wiring. So you need to kill the circuit and pull the receptacle from the wall and inspect it for damage and make any repairs necessary. Personally I would replace the receptacle and make sure your wiring did not overheat and damage the insulation. If the wiring is damaged you need to trim it back. If the wire is then too short you need to pigtail it and reattach it to the new receptacle.

Sorry to deliver the bad news, but having a freezer compressor and a washer motor on the same circuit can cause a shortened life for each appliance. So you really do need to correct that.

Good luck and stay safe.

Comment: I should have read further prior to leaving a comment but agree depending on the circuit size.